# Why are the roots of $x^3+2=0 $: $-2^{1/3}, (-2)^{1/3}$, and $-(-1)^{2/3} 2^{1/3}$?

Tags: complex-numbers, roots

For some reason I can't understand why the roots of $x^3+2=0$ are:

$$x = -\sqrt[3]{2}$$
$$x = \sqrt[3]{-2}$$
$$x = -(-1)^\frac{2}{3} \sqrt[3]{2}$$

I thought it was easier to solve this equation by doing this (I'm probably wrong):

$$x^3+2=0
\iff x^3=-2 \iff x=  \pm \sqrt[3]{-2} $$

I put the function on a graph and saw that  $x = -\sqrt[3]{2}$ was indeed the real root of it. However, I can't understand why.

(I started learning imaginary numbers and complex roots a few days ago so that might explain my reasoning.)

Thank you!

Kenny

Comment: Instead, try factoring it as a sum of cubes. See what happens.

Comment: If you took those from Wolfram Alpha, maybe look at [(-2)^(1/3)](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(-2)%5E(1%2F3)) instead, to see the more familiar forms.

Comment: When $x^3=-2$ this means that $x=+(-2)^{1/3}$ but there is no $\pm$ before the root. That is don't use $\pm$.

Answer (score 2):

Note the three solutions of $x^3+2=0$ are
\begin{align*}
&\{-\sqrt[3]{2},+\sqrt[3]{-1}\cdot\sqrt[3]{2},-\sqrt[3]{-1}\cdot\sqrt[3]{2}\}=\left\{\left.-\sqrt[3]{2}\cdot \exp\left(\frac{2k\pi i}{3}\right)\right|k=0,1,2\right\}
\end{align*}
with 
$\exp\left(\frac{2k\pi i}{3}\right), k=0,1,2$ the three *[roots of unity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_of_unity)*.

> - The key to the three different solutions are the three *roots of unity*, the vertices of a regular $3$-gon at $\left\{1,\pm \exp\left(\frac{2\pi i}{3}\right)\right\}$ scaled by $\sqrt[3]{2}$ and rotated by $\pi$.
>
> \begin{align*}
> z^3=1\quad\rightarrow\quad\left(\frac{z}{\sqrt[3]{2}}\right)^3=1\quad\rightarrow\quad\left(-\frac{z}{\sqrt[3]{2}}\right)^3=1\\
> \end{align*}
>
> which is
>
> \begin{align*}
> z^3=1\quad\rightarrow\quad z^3=2\quad\rightarrow\quad z^3=-2\\
> \end{align*}
>
> - In general we consider $x^n=1$ and $n$ roots of unity forming a regular $n$-gon.
> - The special case with only two solutions ($\pm$) is valid for *quadratic* equations as in
>     \begin{align*}
>   x^2+2=0\quad\iff \quad x^2=-2 \quad\iff \quad x=  \pm \sqrt{-2}
>   \end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

They are roots because if you plug them into the equation, they give you zero (check it!). If you are asking HOW to find roots of a polynomial of this form, I would suggest factoring out $(x+\sqrt[3]{2})$ first (because you know that $- \sqrt[3]{2}$ is a root) and then using the quadratic formula to find the other roots.